# Admin/panel/login/Django/admin panel is not working/"Admins matching query does not exist"

Tags: python, django-admin, admin

I am unable to login to Django admin panel, I am facing an error "Admins matching query does not exist". Just a few days ago, I was solving this error. This is a common error in Django, Fix this error in just a few steps....

Step-1 : First check if your Django project runserver is running, If the server is not running then restart the server using the command-- python manage.py runserver.

Step-2 : Secondly use it to login Django admin panel with mentioned command --- python manage.py createsuperuser .

Finally, This error has been corrected Happpy Codding.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.